# How do I call a function that expects a Byte[][][] parameter?

Tags: c#

What kind of variable should I initialize and how do I do it?

For example

```
byte[][][] data = ?????;
```

The function is from LibJpeg.NET library. The function definition is

```
Int32 jpeg_read_raw_data (
    Byte[][][] data,
    Int32 max_lines
)
```

There is no good documentation for this function, so I don't know what to send it, but I want to try to send something and see what the function will return.

The problem is that I don't know how to call it.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? I assume you are trying to open a JPEG image?

Comment: yes i am trying to open a jpeg image, but i want to open it in such way that i have access to the 16x16 mcu blocks because i want to join jpeg images without quality lose. this is why the built in function wont do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a short look into the sources of LibJpeg.NET it looks like you should initialize the first dimension of the `data` array with the number of scan lines:

```
byte[][][] data = new byte[max_lines][][];
```

The rest of the array is filled when reading the raw data.

I'm not too familiar with that API so I don't know how you would get the number of scan lines though.

Comment: well i tried that but it dont work with return "call to JPEG library in state 202"

Comment: @Karim: I think max_lines should be the image height divided by the height of the MCU.

Comment: ahh ok, thanks , well using this library is killing me. but i will try to figure it out. the big problem really is that there is no documentation to read:(

Comment: Maybe you can find a library with a better documentation then? I was always quite satisfied with ImageMagick(.NET).

Answer (score 2):

```
byte[][][] data is a 3 dimensional array, allocate it accordingly

= {{{0,1,2}{3,4,5}{6,7,8}}
   {{0,1,2}{3,4,5}{6,7,8}}
   {{0,1,2}{3,4,5}{6,7,8}}}
```

NOTE! THIS WILL NOT WORK!  This is a jagged array, so unless you define data as byte[3,3,3] then you are going to go nowhere.

It occurred to me: I have no idea why you are using this library. Is there a reason the built in .NET JPEG classes aren't sufficient? If so, I imagine there would be a way to use the LibJpeg.NET library to get a byte stream from a file and arrange it into a 3D array. This seems like a very "hacky" way to do this, and it makes me wonder if it's just a port of a C library with no updates to fit into a framework like .NET or even OOP.

Comment: I like the way you initialize the array, but are you sure this works? As far as I know, these initializers only work on multi-dimensional arrays, not on jagged arrays.

Comment: yeah i am trying to joine several jpeg files losslessly, and so the built in .net image classes wont do it. but anyway i dont want to initialize the array to any value because its supposed that the library will give me an array with values so its should be an empty array and better with no dimentions since i dont know what the library will return. (i know only the first lenght since i can set it to 100 and the set the max_lines param to 100 too)

Comment: You are right Heinzi! I didn't even think about the fact that it's a jagged array and not 3 dimensional.  Not something I normally have to deal with!

Answer (score 2):

`byte[][][]` is an array of (arrays of (arrays of bytes)), also called a *jagged array*. It's *not* the same as a three-dimensional array (e.g. `byte[,,] x = new byte[10,5,3];`).

Here is an example for allocating and initializing such a structure:

```
        byte[][][] a = new byte[10][][];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            a[i] = new byte[5][];
            for (int ii = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                a[i][ii] = new byte[3];
                a[i][ii][0] = 42;
                a[i][ii][1] = 52;
                a[i][ii][2] = 62;
            }
        }
```

Oh, and by the way, here's a related question: [C# 3 dimensional array definition issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/694510/c-3-dimensional-array-definition-issue).

And here's the MSDN entry on jagged arrays: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx.

Comment: well i tried to intialize the array as u did but the library returned an error [Improper call to JPEG library in state 202]

Answer (score 1):

Just to correct firoso's answer, you **can** allocate arrays like that, he just has not specified the types as required in C# (His code would work in Java, AFAIK)

```
private byte[][][] lol =
        {
            new[]
                {
                    new byte[] {0, 1, 2},
                    new byte[] {3, 4, 5},
                    new byte[] {6, 7, 8}
                },
            new[]
                {
                    new byte[] {0, 1, 2},
                    new byte[] {3, 4, 5},
                    new byte[] {6, 7, 8}
                },
            new[]
                {
                    new byte[] {0, 1, 2},
                    new byte[] {3, 4, 5},
                    new byte[] {6, 7, 8}
                }
        };
```

The `new[]` is actually a shortcut for `new byte[][]` and the `new byte[]` cannot be shortened to `new[]` as then the compiler infers the numbers types as `int`.

I would **not** recommend using this method if you can use Heinzi's iterative method instead; I am only pointing out it is possible to allocate multidimensional arrays like this (it is good for a lot of specific data).