# How to print C# 3D jagged array

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, printing

From @Henk Holterman's [response regarding C# 3 dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/694510/c-sharp-3-dimensional-array-definition-issue) (answered Mar 29 '09 at 12:05), how do you print foos to the console:

```
Foo[][][] foos = new Foo[2][][];

for (int a = 0; a < foos.Length; a++)
{
  foos[a] = new Foo[3][];
  for (int b = 0; b < foos[a].Length; b++)
  {
     foos[a][b] = new Foo [4];

     for (int c = 0; c < foos[a][b].Length; c++)
        foos[a][b][c] = new Foo();
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by printing foos to the console?

Comment: My bad - a little clarification required: I created class Foo:

public class Foo
{
    public string member;
}

and after the last line of code where new Foo() is created, I added:
`foos[row][col][image].member = "test" + "[" + row +"][" + col + "][" +image + "]";`

Now I'd like to iterate through foos and print each member to the console.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is fairly simple to do. Use three for statements to loop through each indexer to get to each instance of Foos.

```
        for (int x = 0; x < foos.Length; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < foos[x].Length; y++) {
                for (int z = 0; z < foos[x][y].Length; z++) {
                    Console.WriteLine(foos[x][y][z].Member);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you.