# How to copy C# 3D jagged array

Tags: c#, arrays, 3d, copy

I need to (initially) copy a C# 3D jagged array, [foos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32402880/how-to-print-c-sharp-3d-jagged-array), to another 3D array (and eventually add x, y, z dimensions). I thought I could use the same syntax/logic to copy [foos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32402880/how-to-print-c-sharp-3d-jagged-array) as was used to build foos as I've done below (where row = 2, col = 3, z = 4):

```
private static void copyFooArray(Foo[][][] foos, ref Foo[][][] newArray)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < foos.Length; row++)
    {
        newArray[row] = new Foo[foos[row].Length][];

        for (int col = 0; col < foos[row].Length; col++)
        {
            newArray[row][col] = new Foo[foos[row][col].Length];

            for (int z= 0; z< foos[row][col].Length; z++)
            {
                newArray[row][col][z] = new Foo();
                newArray[row][col][z].member = foos[row][col][z].member;
            }
        }
    }            
        Console.Read();
}
```

but I'm getting `Index was outside the bounds of the array.` on this line:

`newArray[row] = new Foo[foos[row].Length][];`

Why?

Foo Class:

```
public class Foo
{ 
    public string member;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What else could cause that error than the size of the array passed as argument *newArray* being simply not large enough, i.e., its length being smaller than *foos.Length*?

Comment: Seems like you forgot initialize newArray properly. First line of method should be something like  newArray = new Foo[foos.Length][][];

Comment: How are you initializing `newArray`? `Perhaps a List<List<List<Foo>>> `would be more suitable

Comment: Was crafting an answer your when comment was posted @TimurMannapov . I agree with your comment. I guess it depends on when he wants to initialize it.

Comment: I should have mentioned I am initializing newArray:

`Foo[][][] newArray = new Foo[0][][];`

then passing it in my copyFooArray(...) function...

Looks like my question might have been answered below...

Comment: `"and eventually add x, y, z dimensions"` This isnt going to work - arrays in .net are of a fixed length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look like your referenced array is being initialized properly. In order to set the value, your newArray must be initialized as the same size of your original.

For this to work you'd need to pass in something like this:

```
Foo[][][] firstFoo = new Foo[10][][];
Foo[][][] fooToCopy = new Foo[firstFoo.Length][][];

copyFooArray(firstFoo, ref fooToCopy);
```

Also, the ref keyword is unnecessary since arrays are passed by reference in c# anyways.

Comment: Yeah - that was it:

`Foo[][][] newArray = new Foo[fooArray.Length][][];`

Also successfully removed ref keyword.
Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the fix presented in the accepted answer, here's a faster way to do that:

```
   public static int[][][] Copy(int[][][] source)
    {
        int[][][] dest = new int[source.Length][][];
        for (int x = 0; x < source.Length; x++)
        {
            int[][] s = new int[source[x].Length][];
            for (int y = 0; y < source[x].Length; y++)
            {
                int[] n = new int[source[x][y].Length];
                int length = source[x][y].Length * sizeof(int);
                Buffer.BlockCopy(source[x][y], 0, n, 0, length);
                s[y] = n;
            }
            dest[x] = s;
        }
        return dest;
    }
```